# Apache + Action

Tags: apache

Apache 2.2 has "Action *** virtual" directive.
Is it possible to do the same with Apache 2.0.63?

Answer (score 1):

The virtual modifier for Action directive [was introduced in Apache 2.1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_actions.html#action) so this wont work on 2.0